# No detect the external library (Phpoffice) in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, composer-php, phpoffice

Two computers are working on the SAME repository but first computer detect the library and work well but second computer not detect it and show "Error 'PhpOffice\Phpspreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx' not found".

In vendor, the library also exist.

composer.json and composer.lock also the same on both computer.

One thing is that by git ignore, I use yii's composer mechanism at 1st computer but at sec computer(err computer), I add library manually.

Comment: What does "I add library manually" mean? Didn't you run `composer install` on the second computer?

Comment: There is composer problem on that computer so I decide not to use on that computer and to install external library manaully

Comment: If you just copied and pasted your library into `vendor` folder - that's your problem. Never do that, it won't work, `composer` is generating files for autoload, and you didn't included your library in this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a composer package, you absolutely need to install it using composer. This ensures that the autoloader is generated properly and your class can be found through PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Copying library files into `vendor` directory is not enough to install it. During installation Composer creates autoload script with information how to find all classes installed by Composer. If you just copy library files, Composer will not even know that it exist and will not able load any class from it.

If you cannot use Composer on server/computer A, you should install all dependencies on different computer (B) and copy the entire `vendor` directory into server/computer A. Autoload definitions are in `vendor` so it should work if you copy the whole dorectory.